# Add more user roles to a PHP logout redirect function

Tags: php, redirect

I have this function I found which redirects a user to an URL based on their user role. I have pretty much no knowledge of PHP so I need some help to add another user to it so I can see how it works for adding more later if I need to.

In the current function there's only one role; administrator which gets redirected to /login. I'd like to repeat that part, but for a different user to a different URL.

```
function redirect_after_logout( $user_id ) {

    $current_user   = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];

    if($role_name == 'administrator'){
        $redirect_url = site_url('/login/');
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    } 

}
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'redirect_after_logout'  );
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the question! This looks like it is probably a case for branching `elseif` structures -- you can test each possible value for `$role_name` (in this example) by adding `elseif ( $role_name == 'something-else' ) { ... }` after your `if` structure, for each condition you want to test. For more details, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is copy the part in the code that checks which role the user has and redirect somewhere else, like this:

```
function redirect_after_logout( $user_id ) {
    $current_user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    $role_name    = $current_user->roles[0];
    
    if( $role_name == 'administrator' ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( site_url( '/login/' ) );
        exit;
    }
    
    if( $role_name == 'ANOTHER_ROLE' ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( 'URL_WHERE_EVER_YOU_WANT_TO_REDIRECT' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'redirect_after_logout' );
```